# Is it possible to alter the color range for a laptop screen or PC monitor by using software only?

Tags: display, colors

I have run into a display problem on my laptop:

- black color is displayed as red;
- white color is displayed as turquoise.

I knew the reason was one of the two - the cable connecting display to motherboard, or the display itself. External monitor displays no distortions. I ordered a cheap replacement cable, it did not help, so I know the display is the problem.

What I wonder about is - if it's possible to change the colors of the display:

- Instead of black it would display a very dark shade of grey;
- instead of white a very light shade of grey.

Basically I want to alter the color diapason display shows. **I want to take away colors on both ends of the range, and replace them** with dark or light grey.

Any ideas on if this is possible?

These [link1](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/error-lcd-screen-turns-red-on-laptop/), [link2](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2145725/laptop-screen-colors.html) describe the same problem I have. But instead of ordering a new screen I want to find a workaround.

Laptop is Acer 5551-a, uses 32 bit color mode.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows7/calibrate-your-display colour caliberation might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the laptop uses Windows 7, it was possible to use [PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm) - an old shareware piece of software that has a gamma correction option.
I am sure there are plenty of free alternatives.

I set brightness to 70% and contrast to -50%.

The interface presented was similar to what I had seen in PhotoShop (curves interface in image adjustments).
Below is a screenshot for color profile/gamma alteration in PoweStrip.

Changing brightness and contrast made the blackest parts of the screen lighter, and the whitest parts darker.

Screen does not look much different from other laptops/monitors I have in my office, and does not display any distortions anymore.

I know it is a workaround and does not fix the real problem.But it is good enough as a temporary fix while replacement screen arrives.

[image: gamma correction in PowerStrip]

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing on a Linux distribution with `xcalib`:

```
xcalib -clear
xcalib -alter -brightness 2.0
xcalib -alter -contrast 97.0
```

Try to find the right values for brightness (as low as possible) and contrast (as high as possible) so there is not much change overall while simultaneously making the wrong colors disappear.